# Open popup.html using script in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here I am working with chrome my menifest.json file like :

```
    {
  "name": "chrome Demo",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Official addon from chrome",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "star-on.png",
    "popup": "popupnew.html"    
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "cookies",          
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*",
     "contextMenus"
  ],
  "background_page": "background.html"   
}
```

Here it work fine when I click default_icon on browser it will open popup page.

Now my concern is I want to open my popup page using script. "In background I want to write script which able to handle popup page"

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but currently there is no way of opening it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can open popup.html in a new window or tab. While this isn't quite the functionality you are looking for it will have a similar effect. Especially if you format the new window similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [chrome.pageAction.show()](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/pageAction.html#method-show)? I've never had to use this before but I believe it's what you're looking for.

Comment: But isn't that for a pageAction? He uses instead the browserAction.

Comment: Ah sorry, I even reread the question and still read page action some how. I see it now though... "popup page" was what caught me out.